# How can I determine if a persons name indicates that a possessive "s" should be omitted in German?

Tags: php

I am trying to build a function that will give me the correct german possessive form of a name. Let's say I got three names: Lars, Alex & Tina.

The possessive would be "Lars' Autobahn, Alex' Autobahn & Tinas Autobahn".
If the last letter of the name is S or X I would have to add an apostrophe, in every other case I just need to add the S to the name.

But when I use my function it always adds an S to the end of every name (Larss, Alexs, Tinas).

```
function possessive_de($name) {
    if($name[strlen($name) - 1] != 'x' || $name[strlen($name) - 1] != 's') {
        $n = $name.'s';
    } else {
        $n = $name.'&#8217;';
    }
    return $n;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: For documentation purpose - this is the solution if you want to apply the rule to all common names.

```
function possessive_de($name) {
    $lastCharacter = $name[strlen($name) - 1];

    $excluded = ['s','x','z','ß'];

    if(substr($name, -2) == 'ce') {
        return $name . '&#8217;';
    } else if (in_array($lastCharacter, $excluded)) {
        return $name . '&#8217;';
    } else {
        return $name . 's';
    }   
}
```

The output would be:

```
echo possessive_de("Tina"); // echoes Tinas
echo possessive_de("Alex"); // echoes Alex'
echo possessive_de("Lars"); // echoes Lars'
echo possessive_de("Leibniz"); // echoes Leibinz'
echo possessive_de("Maurice"); // echoes Maurice'
```

Comment: your first 2 rules should be equal, not, not equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only marginally related to your question, but you can simplify the function to:

```
function possessive_de($name) 
{
    $lastCharacter = $name[strlen($name) - 1];

    $excluded = [
        's',
        'x',
        'z',
        'ß',
    ];

    if (in_array($lastCharacter, $excluded)) {
        return $name . '&#8217;';
    }

    return $name . 's';
}
```

Following our little conversation in the comments, if you acknowledge that  there are more *endings* of names which could indicate to omit the possessive *s* and instead use an *apostrophe*, try this:

```
function possessive_de($name)
{
    $endings = [
        'ce',
        's',
        'ss',
        'tz',
        'x',
        'z',
        'ß',
    ];

    foreach ($endings as $ending) {
        if (substr($name, -strlen($ending)) === $ending) {
            return $name . '&#8217;';
        }
    }

    return $name . 's';
}
```

**Note** All of the code examples assume that `$name`

- is a non-blank string (consisting of white-space only)
- is trimmed
- is not an empty string

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Glad you like it, @GerritFries!

Comment: Quick note, there appear to be more endings which indicate to omit the *s* and instead use an *apostrophe*, see http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph.

Comment: You are totally right! I never thought about "ce"-ending like in Maurice. Having this in mind I need to do a double check if the last character is an "e" to check if the character before the last is a "c".

Comment: Added an example to include the additional name endings!

Comment: Great! But shouldn't be $length inside foreach loop with strlen($ending)?

Comment: @GerritFries Not sure I understand what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: foreach ($endings as $ending) {
     $length = strlen($ending);
        if (substr($name, -$length) === $ending) {
            return $name . '&#8217;';
        }
    }

Comment: Ha, no need to measure the length of `$name` more often than once. It doesn't change. That's why `strlen()` is invoked once only *before* entering the loop!

Comment: Yeah, but this way the function does not work as it should.

Comment: Apologies, you are actually right! Adjusted the code. See https://3v4l.org/SFKqK!

Comment: Thank you so much. You help me out a lot. Dankeschön! ;)

Comment: Happy to help, @GerritFries!

Answer (score 1):

The `||` should be a `&&`.
You want to check that the last char `is not x` **AND** `is not s`.
Alternatively check wether the last char `is x` **OR** `is s`.

Comment: Ouch! I really feel ashamed now. That was way too simple. Thanks a lot!